# Summing Variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to computer the sum of variable A in R.

This is my dataset and I would like to sum VariableA and Variable B so that I can convert them into a metrics that involves Sum of Variable A/Sum of Variable B in percentages.

[image]

This is the code that I wrote:

[image]

Is this right?

If you need any clarification, please let me know!This is my first time working in R so any advice is welcomed.

Comment: In the code, you may have to change the division part with the `TotalVariable` created

Comment: Please do not provide your data or code as images.  No one wants to type it all in again.   Just paste your code into your question.  For your data, please use `dput` ( e.g. `dput(head(myData, 10))` ) and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Why you cannot try to do the same in Excel/Libreoffice and see whether the results differ or not?

Comment: What happened when you ran that code? Why do you have any concerns about it?

Answer (score 0):

it is correct. For example, if I have:

```
a = rnorm(3)*100 
a
[1] 179.0728564 207.4616680  -0.8553943
b = rnorm(3)*100
b
[1] -109.01319   22.26418 -117.41152
```

Then I can use function sum():

```
out = (sum(a)/sum(b))*100
out
[1] 165.3314
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to do

```
a = 10
b = 20

div = (sum (a)/ sum(b)) * 100

div

[1] 50
```